# Rendering a component based on dynamic route params with mapStateToProps and reselect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I am storing data for various `rooms` in a global app container. I have a sub-container called `roomDetails` that uses a reselect selector to select a room from the global state using `ownProps.params.slug`. This is done using mapStateToProps.

My problem is that when I change route params (`rooms/:roomId`) from:

`rooms/roomid1`

to

`rooms/roomid2`

the component room props are not updating.

I'm changing the route using Link:

`<Link to={"/room/roomid1"} key={"room-roomid1"}>room 1</Link>`

How can I get the component's `room` props to reselect a room from the global rooms state when the route params change?

Note, the room props load as they should on first page load, or if i go to a route that's outside of the dynamic route, and then return. They just don't load correctly when switching between the same dynamic route, where only component properties (route params) are changing.

**RoomDetails/index.js**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return createStructuredSelector({
    room: selectRoom(ownProps.params.roomId),
  });
}
```

...

```
  render() {
    let roomContent = null;
    if (this.props.room) {
      roomContent = (
        <div>
          {this.props.room.get('name')}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {roomContent}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**selectors.js**

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const selectGlobal = () => (state) => state.get('global');

const selectRooms = () => createSelector(
  selectGlobal(),
  (globalState) => globalState.get('rooms')
);

const selectRoom = (roomId) => createSelector(
  selectRooms(),
  (roomsState) => roomsState && roomsState.get(roomId)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reselect will only respond to whatever variables are passed to the first argument. Therefore, you must update some variable whenever that route changes. There are two options that come to mind:

- Implement [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) and then respond to it in your selector
- Dispatch an event that updates the `roomId` in your store on the component mounted at that route.

For the second option, you would do something like this. Say that this component is mounted at the route `/rooms/:roomId`:

```
class Rooms extends Component {
  changeRoom = (roomId = this.props.roomId) => this.props.setRoom(roomId);

  componentDidMount() {
    this.changeRoom();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.roomId !== nextProps.roomId) {
      this.changeRoom(nextProps.roomId);
    }
  }
}
```

Say that this updates `state.room.selected`. You could specify that in your selector.

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const getRooms = state => state.rooms.data;
const getSelected = state => state.rooms.selected;

export const getCurrentRoom = createSelector(
  [ getRooms, getSelected ],
  (rooms, selected) => rooms.find(room.id === selected)
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the selector "selectRoom" respond though since what I'm passing into it (ownProps.params.roomId) _IS_ changing?

Comment: can you console.log it to confirm that it is changing?

Comment: When I do "componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('Next room:', nextProps.params.roomId);
  }", it prints the correct room id every time I click a link to change rooms

Comment: So props.params.roomId (route param) is updating, but props.params.room is not.

Comment: I mean, log it in the selector. Eg: `(rooms, selected) => { console.log(rooms, selected); return rooms.get(selected) }`

Comment: No, the selector is only selecting the room once, even though the arguments to the selector are changing. Is this because I'm using createStructuredSelector? It almost certainly has to do with memoization, I just can't figure out exactly why the selector isn't calling, given that I can confirm the props are changing.

Comment: Also `mapStateToProps` is only being called once. It doesn't call again when the route changes, even though the properties change in `componentWillReceiveProps`

Answer (score 0):

I removed the params from `selectRoom` and changed `mapStateToProps` to:

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  room: selectRoom(),
});
```

I then updated the selectors like this and it's working...

```
const selectGlobal = () => (state) => state.get('global');

const selectedRoom = () => (state, props) => props && props.params.roomId;

const selectRooms = () => createSelector(
  selectGlobal(),
  (globalState) => globalState.get('rooms')
);

const selectRoom = () => createSelector(
  selectRooms(),
  selectedRoom(),
  (roomsState, roomId) => roomsState.get(roomId)
);
```

I still don't understand why the selector wasn't being called when I was passing `props.params.roomId` to it...

Maybe since `selectRooms()` has no argument it always gets called?